# Python Jupyter Notebook: How to Change Python Executable for Unix Without Environments?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have different Python environments on my Ubuntu machine:

- `/home/user/anaconda3/envs/untitled/bin/python`
- `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python`

What is the easiest way to let an ipython / jupyter notebook work with either the first or the second python environment (if possible it would be good if I do not need to create a virtual environment for that)?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you already have two conda environments available on your machine. You [could install the kernelspec for each one](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments), and you should be able to use Jupyter with either.

```
# for /home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python
source activate my_env 
python -m ipykernel install --user --name my_env --display-name "Python (my_env)"
source deactivate
```

And now you should see Python (my_env) as an available kernel in Jupyter.

Comment: If you get a `no module named ipykernel` error, run `conda install ipykernel` while in `my_env`.